# Can I make onclick fire after mousedown, but before mouseup event?

Tags: javascript

I need audio to play after touchstart and just before a touchend (by holding a button with a finger ). It works by Android, but iOS needs onclick event to start on playing.
Is there any way to change an order of this events?

Thanks

Comment: A click is by definition a mousedown followed by a mouseup.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You must utilise the onmousedown and onmouseup events.

```
<p onmousedown="myFunction()">Click the text!</p>
<p onmouseup="mouseUp()">Click the text!</p>
```